# ccall with Array type in signature calling a struct in C from Julia

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, julia

I am having trouble with calling a C function from Julia. This may be generally useful question, but I'll describe it here in the concrete setting I am struggling with. I am trying to create a `bson` object:

```
BSONObject("{a:1}")
```

so this object's constructor is called:

```
BSONObject(jsonString::String) = begin
    jsonCStr = bytestring(jsonString)
    bsonError = BSONError()
    _wrap_ = ccall(
        (:bson_new_from_json, libbson),
        Ptr{Void}, (Ptr{Uint8}, Csize_t, Ptr{Uint8}),
        jsonCStr,
        length(jsonCStr),
        bsonError._wrap_
        )
    _wrap_ != C_NULL || error(bsonError)
    bsonObject = new(_wrap_, None)
    finalizer(bsonObject, destroy)
    return bsonObject
end
```

in the https://github.com/pzion/LibBSON.jl/blob/master/src/BSONObject.jl LibBSON package needed to handle MongoDB queries, but the setting is not particularly important. What is important is the `ccall`, which passes a string, `jsonCStr`, this string's length, and `bsonError._wrap_`. This last object comes from https://github.com/pzion/LibBSON.jl/blob/master/src/BSONError.jl and is an array:

```
type BSONError
    _wrap_::Vector{Uint8}

    function BSONError()
        return new(Array(Uint8, 512))
    end
end
```

created in the above constructor of `BSONError` object, an array of 512 `Uint8`'s. This Julia `bsonError._wrap_` refers to the following `struct` in C:

```
typedef struct
{
   uint32_t domain;
   uint32_t code;
   char     message[504];
} bson_error_t;
```

see on http://api.mongodb.org/libbson/current/bson_error_t.html, and this struct is of length 4 + 4 + 504 = 512, so it looks OK.

Now going back to the `ccall`, its type signature is Ok: `Ptr{Uint8}` points to the string, `Csize_t` is the type of its size, and Ptr{Uint8} points to the `struct`. This latter, however, returns with an error message:

```
LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Ptr{UInt8}}, ::Array{UInt8,1})
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Ptr{UInt8}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T<:Union{Int8,UInt8}}(::Type{Ptr{T<:Union{Int8,UInt8}}}, !Matched::Cstring)
  convert{T}(::Type{Ptr{T}}, !Matched::UInt64)
  ...
while loading In[2], in expression starting on line 1

 in convert at /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4/LibBSON/src/BSONError.jl:21
 in call at /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4/LibBSON/src/BSONObject.jl:33
```

apparently, trying to convert the `Array` to a type `Ptr{UInt8}`.

The Julia manual http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#mapping-c-types-to-julia says in the 'Mapping C Types to Julia' section's 'Bits Types' subsection that a Julia `Array{T,N}` should be passed as `Ptr{T}`, where `T` is `UInt8` in this case. So the Julia `ccall` looks ok, but there is still that error message. It is a pretty burning problem since it prevents more complex queries in the database. Any suggestions as to how to remedy this `ccall` problem?

P.S. Note if you install the Mongo package it comes with the LibBSON package and the libbson C library.

Comment: I just found a bug in BSONError.js that causes the problem and am writing up an answer. I think it is not related to a version.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is unrelated to the `ccall`. It is caused by [this line](https://github.com/pzion/LibBSON.jl/blob/c854c7df053533070c7d1e8f2f6e708410ab438c/src/BSONError.jl#L21), as indicated in the stack trace.

In 0.4, there is no longer a `convert{T}(::Type{Ptr{T}},Array{T})` function.

`ccall` calls converts its argument using the (non-exported) `unsafe_convert` method (which is why the above code doesn't cause an error). If you want a `Ptr` object in user code, the easiest way is to use the `pointer` method.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your last sentence? I am not (yet) an expert  on `ccall` and conversions.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the BSONError.jl has had a bug, the

```
return bytestring(convert(Ptr{Uint8}, bsonError._wrap_[9:end]))
```

should be

```
return bytestring(bsonError._wrap_[9:end])
```

in the BSONError.jl's `convert` function. That is, the error could not be printed out because the error printing is buggy.

Fixing that, from the error message received form C it turns out that the correct bson format is

BSONObject("{\"a\":1}")

to create a bson object.

Comment: If you found a bug, would you be so friendly and report it as issue at https://github.com/pzion/LibBSON.jl/issues ?